# Как улучшить цикл?

Tags: php

Добро времени. У меня есть вот такой цикл

```
for ($i=0;$i<150;$i++){
preg_match_all("/(http:\/\/)?(my\.mail\.ru)(\/)([^\/]+)(\/)([^\/]+)(\/)/i",
                        $code, $matches);
                    $host = $matches[0][$i];//тут я подключил элементы массива к счетчику
                    $host2 = $host.",\n";
                if (strlen($host2)<=50)
                    file_put_contents("pars.txt",$host2,FILE_APPEND);
                    }
```

Только мне нужно чтобы он работал не 150 раз как я сделал наугад) а пока не просмотрит страницу. А то он 30 секунд работает а потом ошибку выдаёт. Помогите люди добрые.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

а точно нужно каждый раз получать одно и тоже?

```
preg_match_all("/(http:\/\/)?(my\.mail\.ru)(\/)([^\/]+)(\/)([^\/]+)(\/)/i",
                    $code, $matches);
for ($i=0;$i<count($matches[0]);$i++){
   $host = $matches[0][$i];
   $host2 = $host.",\n";
   if (strlen($host2)<=50)
        file_put_contents("pars.txt",$host2,FILE_APPEND);
}
```

то есть, в цикле вызывать `preg_match_all` каждый раз не нужно - оно все равно возвратит одно и тоже. А операция затратная. Также, после вызова, кол-во элементов известно, так что можно делать цикл правильно.

Comment: Моя цель при просмотре исходного кода вытаскивать строки с емэйлами
и записывать их в текстовый файл в столбик через запятую

Comment: работает теперь быстрее?

Comment: да спасибо