# Как можно проще всего спарсить все темы с форума?

Tags: php

Как можно проще всего спарсить все темы с форума на php? Интересует именно это страница http://www.kharkovforum.com/forumdisplay.php?f=112. Подскажите идею, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как бы всё =)

```
<?php

    define("PARSE_LINK", "http://www.kharkovforum.com/forumdisplay.php?f=112");

    $page = file_get_contents(PARSE_LINK);

    $matches = array();

    $pattern = "#<a href=\"showthread\.php\?s=[a-z0-9]+&amp;t=[0-9]+\" id=\"[a-z0-9_]+\">(.)+</a>#";

    preg_match_all($pattern, $page, $matches);

    if( $count = count($matches[0]) )
    {
        echo "<p>Найдено: " . $count . "</p>";

        foreach($matches[0] as $link)
            echo $link . "<br/>\r\n";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<p>Ничего не нашёл :(</p>";
        exit;
    }

?>
```

Можно ещё через preg_replace() в ссылку вставить URI сайта, тогда можно будет щёлкать по ним. =)

Comment: Спасибо, а не подскажете как решить проблему с кодировками, если на сервере utf-8, а сайт, который парсим windows-1251, в итоге результат - кракозябры. Как можно решить этот момент?

Comment: Ожидал такой вопрос. Под строчкой $page = file_get_contents(PARSE_LINK);
Пишем: $page = iconv("utf-8","cp1251", $page);

Всё! Теперь у вас всегда корректная страница. А вообще я объявляю ещё 2 константы вначале файла, там декларирую входящую кодировку и ту, которую хотим получить.

P.S. По дефолту лучше всегда так делать, даже если кодировка в порядке.
Перед тем как написать сюда пример парсера, file_get_contents выдавал нормальную cp1251.

Answer (score 4):

Вначале смотрите на этот [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/175602/php-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB) и понимаете, что нужны регулярки.

На первый взгляд, ругулярка `<td class="alt1".*title="(.*)">` должна помочь.

А текст страницы получить - это уже избитый вопрос.

Comment: <холивар моде он>парсить HTML регулярными выражениями -- зло. Особенно если в язык встроен настоящий парсер.

Comment: Смотря для чего. В данном случае было слово "проще". А так я бы посоветовал [phpquery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) и далее по [списку](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php)

Comment: @KoVadim: мне кажется, проще всего сделать правильно, и не заморачиваться вопросами "а почему оно не работает в 1% случаев". Хотя, конечно, "проще всего" можно интерпретировать по-разному. Например, не по "объёму кода", а по "объёму необходимых знаний".

ЗЫ: спасибо за ссылку на `phpquery`!

Comment: Мне, если нужно просто спарсить прям сейчас и завтра этот код уже не мне не нужен будет (ну например, захотел напарсить я себе цитат с баша), то я скорее всего напишу на базе регулярки. Но код выделю в отдельную функцию. Если, через некоторое время я снова вернусь к коду и мне нужно будет для продакшина - я подумаю о том, что бы заменить подобными библиотеками.  **Но это лишь по той причине, что я регулярки знаю лучше.** и соотношение скорость/качество в данном случае будет максимальным.

Comment: Спасибо, за помощь, но регулярка не работает!

Comment: Так надо на код смотреть и регулярку творчески модифицировать. Ссылки на темы, например, можно выдёргивать по  href="showthread.php?t=..."